# unable to call public function from Java class in Kotlin class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I have a full Java app that displays some videos using recyclerview and its working. I'm trying to migrated it to a Kotlin app, but have decided to leave one class in Java for now because the logic is fairly complicated.

The purpose of the Java class is to display the exo player video data for a recycler view.

But in my main activity, which is in Kotlin, I need to call one of its functions to load some data.

Originally, in the java app main activity I init the recyclerview like this (recyclerview.setMediaObjects and recyclerview.setAdapter are the important parts)

```
   private com.example.androidchallengejava.VideoPlayerRecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    private ArrayList<MediaObject> mMediaObjects = new ArrayList<MediaObject>();


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
   
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        VerticalSpacingItemDecorator itemDecorator = new VerticalSpacingItemDecorator(10);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);


        ArrayList<MediaObject> mediaObject = new ArrayList<MediaObject>(mMediaObjects);
        mRecyclerView.setMediaObjects(mediaObject);

        com.example.androidchallengejava.VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter adapter = new com.example.androidchallengejava.VideoPlayerRecyclerAdapter(mediaObject, initGlide());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

That's working, so I'm trying to do something similar in my Kotlin app. I have the Kotlin app main activity set up like this:

(Sorry VODs here are the same as media objects)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)


        binding.recyclerView.adapter = VideoPlayerAdapter(list)

        binding.recyclerView.setVODs()
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.hasFixedSize()
    }
}
```

but setMediaObjects is in red.

So basically I'm able to access setMediaObjects off of mRecyclerView when I'm in the Java MainActivity, but when I use the binding in the Kotlin MainActivity the method isn't available.

The below Java class is exactly the same in each app.  setVODs is all the way at the bottom.

Can anyone tell me the problem? Thanks

```
public class VideoPlayerRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayerRecyclerView";

    private enum VolumeState {ON, OFF};

    // ui
    private ImageView thumbnail, volumeControl;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private View viewHolderParent;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    private PlayerView videoSurfaceView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer videoPlayer;

    // vars
    private ArrayList<VOD> vods = new ArrayList<>();
    private int videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = 0;
    private int screenDefaultHeight = 0;
    private Context context;
    private int playPosition = -1;
    private boolean isVideoViewAdded;
    //glide
    private RequestManager requestManager;

    // controlling playback state
    private VolumeState volumeState;

    public VideoPlayerRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public VideoPlayerRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }


    private void init(Context context){
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        Point point = new Point();
        display.getSize(point);
        videoSurfaceDefaultHeight = point.x;
        screenDefaultHeight = point.y;

        videoSurfaceView = new PlayerView(this.context);
        //for adding surface views dynamically - in case its inserted into a view it doesn't fit perfectly
        videoSurfaceView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);


        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector =
                new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        // 2. Create the exo player
        videoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
        // Bind the player to the view.
        videoSurfaceView.setUseController(false);
        videoSurfaceView.setPlayer(videoPlayer);

        addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                //you have to make sure the recycler view has stopped before taking actions
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged: called.");
                    if(thumbnail != null){ // show the old thumbnail


                        //will you need thumbnails for you app??
                        thumbnail.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    }

                    // There's a special case when the end of the list has been reached.
                    // Need to handle that with this bit of logic

                    //add a query here for more videos?
                    if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){
                        playVideo(true);
                    }
                    else{
                        playVideo(false);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });

        addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
                if (viewHolderParent != null && viewHolderParent.equals(view)) {
                    resetVideoView();
                }

            }
        });


        //controles playback for exo player
        videoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, @Nullable Object manifest, int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                switch (playbackState) {

                    case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Buffering video.");
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        }

                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Video ended.");
                        videoPlayer.seekTo(0);
                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_IDLE:

                        break;
                    case Player.STATE_READY:
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerStateChanged: Ready to play.");
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
                        }
                        if(!isVideoViewAdded){
                            addVideoView();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRepeatModeChanged(int repeatMode) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onShuffleModeEnabledChanged(boolean shuffleModeEnabled) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPositionDiscontinuity(int reason) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPlaybackParametersChanged(PlaybackParameters playbackParameters) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSeekProcessed() {

            }
        });
    }

    public void playVideo(boolean isEndOfList) {

        int targetPosition;

        //determines which video to play given more than one list item on the screen
        if(!isEndOfList){
            //first and last VISIBLE list items
            int startPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int endPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();

            // if there is more than 2 list-items on the screen, set the difference to be 1
            if (endPosition - startPosition > 1) {
                endPosition = startPosition + 1;
            }

            // something is wrong. return.
            if (startPosition < 0 || endPosition < 0) {
                return;
            }

            // if there is more than 1 list-item on the screen
            if (startPosition != endPosition) {
                int startPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(startPosition);
                int endPositionVideoHeight = getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(endPosition);

                //what list item we are going to play
                targetPosition = startPositionVideoHeight > endPositionVideoHeight ? startPosition : endPosition;
            }
            else {
                //single list item
                targetPosition = startPosition;
            }
        }
        else{
            targetPosition = vods.size() - 1;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "playVideo: target position: " + targetPosition);

        // video is already playing so return
        if (targetPosition == playPosition) {
            return;
        }

        // set the position of the list-item that is to be played
        playPosition = targetPosition;
        if (videoSurfaceView == null) {
            return;
        }

        // remove any old surface views from previously playing videos
        videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView);

        int currentPosition = targetPosition - ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        View child = getChildAt(currentPosition);
        if (child == null) {
            return;
        }
//
//        VideoPlayerViewHolder holder = (VideoPlayerViewHolder) child.getTag();
//        if (holder == null) {
//            playPosition = -1;
//            return;
//        }
//        thumbnail = holder.thumbnail;
//        progressBar = holder.progressBar;
//        volumeControl = holder.volumeControl;
//        viewHolderParent = holder.itemView;
//        requestManager = holder.requestManager;
//        frameLayout = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.media_container);

        videoSurfaceView.setPlayer(videoPlayer);


        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                context, Util.getUserAgent(context, "RecyclerView VideoPlayer"));
        String mediaUrl = vods.get(targetPosition).getMedia_url();
        if (mediaUrl != null) {
            MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(mediaUrl));
            videoPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
            videoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            //HlsMediaSource instead of ExractorMediasource above
        }
    }



    /**
     * Returns the visible region of the video surface on the screen.
     * if some is cut off, it will return less than the @videoSurfaceDefaultHeight
     * @param playPosition
     * @return
     */
    private int getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight(int playPosition) {
        int at = playPosition - ((LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        Log.d(TAG, "getVisibleVideoSurfaceHeight: at: " + at);

        View child = getChildAt(at);
        if (child == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int[] location = new int[2];
        child.getLocationInWindow(location);

        if (location[1] < 0) {
            return location[1] + videoSurfaceDefaultHeight;
        } else {
            return screenDefaultHeight - location[1];
        }
    }


    private void removeVideoView(PlayerView videoView) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) videoView.getParent();
        if (parent == null) {
            return;
        }

        int index = parent.indexOfChild(videoView);
        if (index >= 0) {
            parent.removeViewAt(index);
            isVideoViewAdded = false;
            viewHolderParent.setOnClickListener(null);
        }

    }

    private void addVideoView(){
        frameLayout.addView(videoSurfaceView);
        isVideoViewAdded = true;
        videoSurfaceView.requestFocus();
        videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        videoSurfaceView.setAlpha(1);
        thumbnail.setVisibility(GONE);
    }

    private void resetVideoView(){
        if(isVideoViewAdded){
            removeVideoView(videoSurfaceView);
            playPosition = -1;
            videoSurfaceView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            thumbnail.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void releasePlayer() {

        if (videoPlayer != null) {
            videoPlayer.release();
            videoPlayer = null;
        }

        viewHolderParent = null;
    }





    public void setVODs(ArrayList<VOD> vods){
        this.vods = vods;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like an issue in your XML declaring the right view type, not a Kotlin vs. Java issue.

Comment: Looks like you were right, I needed to have it point to my custom recycler view in the xml. If you want to answer I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: I had to change <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView> to <com.example.pac_12androidchallenge.VideoPlayerRecyclerView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior would be explained by you accidentally declaring the view type in XML as some type other than your custom class, like maybe as a plain RecyclerView. Since you’re using view binding now, you’re getting a compile time error instead of runtime error casting to the wrong type. You would have the same issue with this layout if using view binding with Java.